# Markov Chain Questions

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes, markov-chains, markov-process

I've been stuck on these problems for a while. I keep banging my head against the wall, but my calculations are incorrect each time. I sum the probabilities together for each possibility (it's a letter + it's a letter etc.), but I must have gotten the wrong impression from my lecturer's notes about markov chains.

[image]

1. What is the probability that the next 3 symbols are digits?

(.7 + .2 + .2)

2. What is the probability that the next 2 symbols are digits and the 2 symbols after that are letters?

(1-.5) + .3 + .3

3. Predict the probability

that the symbol two away from the current letter is also a letter.

.3 + .2 + .2

Edit: As you can tell by these calculations, I am confused.

Comment: You might want to stop banging your head against the wall and start showing your calculations instead.

Comment: @Did alright the head banging will pause and the calculations will be shown

Comment: You only add probabilities together if you are asking "this or that" and they are mutually exclusive events.  A probability of $.7+.2+.2=1.1$ doesn't even make sense (*probabilities must be between $0$ and $1$*).  Apply the multiplication principle instead.  $Pr(A\cap B)=Pr(A)\cdot Pr(B\mid A)$

Comment: @JMoravitz so how do I apply that principle to number 1? I think I'm misunderstanding markov chains

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Note: the way the matrix is written is as a row-stochastic matrix (rows sum to one).  Many other texts prefer writing markov chains as column-stochastic matrices instead (where columns add to one).  Keep this in mind when reading other books and literature.  What follows will be in regards to row-stochastic matrices*

The current symbol is a letter (*given as a part of the problem statement*).  We ask what is the probability that the next symbol is a digit?

The fact that the current symbol is a letter implies that we should look at the first row.  Where we want to end up corresponds to which column to read.  The probability of going from state one(*letter*) to state two(*digit*) lies at the first row second column entry.  In this case the entry is a $.1$.  In other words, $Pr(letter\mapsto digit)=0.1$

When starting as a digit, we want to see what the probability that the following letter is again a digit.  Looking at the second row (*since that is the current state*), we look at the second column entry (*since that is where we want to find the probability of ending up*).  We see in the matrix that this is an $0.3$.  In other words, $Pr(digit\mapsto digit)=0.3$

Starting as a letter, what is the probability that the next two characters are both digits?  Well, first it would have to be going from letter to digit, and then from digit to digit.

$Pr(letter\mapsto digit\mapsto digit) = Pr(letter\mapsto digit)\cdot Pr(digit\mapsto digit) = 0.1\cdot 0.3$

How about starting as a letter and the next three characters all being digits?

> $0.1\cdot 0.3\cdot 0.3$

What about the next two being digits and the two after that being letters?

$Pr(letter\mapsto digit\mapsto digit\mapsto letter\mapsto letter) = Pr(letter\mapsto digit)\cdot Pr(digit\mapsto digit)\cdot Pr(digit\mapsto letter)\cdot Pr(letter\mapsto letter)$

For the third part, note that you can choose to either draw yourself a tree diagram and solve it that way, but it is more convenient to use properties of stochastic matrices.  Simply raising the matrix to the power $n$ corresponds to moving $n$ time-steps away.  In other words, the row $a$ column $b$ entry corresponds to the probability to move from state $a$ to state $b$ in exactly $n$ steps.

Approaching directly via tree diagram though, one can break into cases based on what the inbetween character is.  It will be one of the following:  $letter\mapsto letter\mapsto letter$, $letter\mapsto digit\mapsto letter$, $letter\mapsto other\mapsto letter$.  Applying a mixture of addition principle and multiplication principle, we have: $Pr(letter\mapsto ?\mapsto letter) = Pr(letter\mapsto letter)Pr(letter\mapsto letter) + Pr(letter\mapsto digit)Pr(digit\mapsto letter) + Pr(letter\mapsto other)Pr(other\mapsto letter)$

---

A few other reminders:

$Pr(A~\text{or}~B~\text{happening})=Pr(A\cup B)$

$Pr(A~\text{and}~B~\text{happening})=Pr(A\cap B)$

Inclusion exclusion (*two event version*):  $Pr(A\cup B) = Pr(A)+Pr(B)-Pr(A\cap B)$

Addition principle **for mutually exclusive events**: $Pr(A\cup B)= Pr(A)+Pr(B)$

Multiplication principle (*two event version*):  $Pr(A\cap B)= Pr(A)\cdot Pr(B\mid A)$

Multiplication principle for **independent** events: $Pr(A\cap B)=Pr(A)\cdot Pr(B)$

Comment: Is the probability P(letter |---> letter) 0.7?

Comment: @user2598152 yes, according to the matrix that you are given.  Since being a letter corresponds to state one, traveling from state one to state one is the first row first column entry.